# disable text enhance script

Tags: javascript, ads

Does someone have the solution to disable text enhance?

I'm not talking about deleting the plugins etc.
What I want is put a script in my php or javascript that disables every text enhance if the user is infected.
I know this is possible because in facebook these ads don't show up.

Comment: Can u explain your query a little more..?
Or simply paste your inpogress code here.... appreciated :)

Comment: @VikashPandey He seems to be talking about malware browser extensions that automatically enable [text-enhance.com](http://text-enhance.com/) on random pages. Here is a [forum post](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/339733-Has-anyone-else-here-been-zapped-by-text-enhance) and [article](http://wafflesatnoon.com/2011/10/05/seeing-unwanted-text-enhance-ads/) about that problem. I think the poster wants to cancel the effects of those extensions on his site, so that even if the user has one of those extensions, they don't see the Text Enhance popups.

Comment: I don't have any code written down atm because I have no idea where to start... I want a script that prevents words coloring blue (because of 3rd party ads/malware.) When hovering over this colored text, a box with an ad in it appears.. Please lookup "text enhance" for more info.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Yes, you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I suggest finding sample popups on [text-enhance.com](http://text-enhance.com/) and sites that use it, and inspecting how those popups are implemented, using your browser's inspector such as [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/). Do the popups only apply to links with a certain `class` attribute? Is there a `text-enhance.js` script file that you can view the source of? When you find how the script adds its popups, you can either stop it adding them in the first place or remove them after they are added.

Answer (score 0):

From http://adobe.github.io/Spry/articles/best_practices/progressive_enhancement.html

> #### Progressive Enhancement with Spry
>
> Progressive enhancement is a technique used by web developers to
>   ensure that their pages are accessible to as wide an audience as
>   possible while at the same time trying to take advantage of the latest
>   browser enhancements to provide the best user experience for their
>   users. The basic idea behind progressive enhancement is to start off
>   by creating a basic version of your page that contains your content
>   and semantic markup that is supported by the lowest common denominator
>   browser you intend to target. Once you are done, you can then alter
>   the display and behavior of elements on the page with the use of
>   technologies such as CSS, JavaScript, and Flash. By designing your
>   pages in this manner, the user and any assistive technologies they
>   use, or search engine spiders, should be able to access your page
>   content, even in the absence of CSS, JavaScript and Flash. This
>   document will give examples of how to use the various components
>   within Spry in a progressive enhancement scenario and introduce some
>   techniques and utilities that will hopefully make it easy: